# Angular resolver not resolving?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

This is a demo of the problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-with-resolver-observable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpost-resolver.service.ts

Switching out `this.observeLoading$` with `of(false)` makes it work, so I think it has something to do with the fact that `this.observeLoading$` is notified by a `ReplaySubject` that can provide more than one notification ...

Here are more details:

First this does resolve:

```
    async resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        const topic = await of(false).pipe(
            switchMap((v) =>{
                console.log("MADE IT THIS FAR: ", v)
                return of(new Topic)
            })).toPromise()
        console.log("THE TOPIC RETURNED IS", topic)

        return topic;
```

In the above case it logs everything and performs the navigation.

In the below case it logs "MADE IT THIS FAR: false", but then it hangs.

```
    async resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        const id = route.paramMap.get('id')
        const topic = await this.cs.loadingTopicStore$.pipe(
            switchMap((v) =>{
                console.log("MADE IT THIS FAR: ", v)
                return of(new Topic)
            })).toPromise()
        console.log("THE TOPIC RETURNED IS", topic)

        return topic;
```

As far as I can tell the two scenarios are essentially the same.  The only difference is in the first we are using `of(false)` and in the second we are using `this.cs.loadingTopicStore$`, and both of these are firing since "MADE IT THIS FAR: " is logged in both cases.

Thoughts?

### Filed an Issue with Angular

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34535

Comment: You could trying to replace the `switchMap` to a `map` and return the value directly instead of an `of()` operator or is it necessary to use a `switchMap`?

Comment: what is `this.cs.loadingTopicStore$`? how you define it and how you fire it.

Comment: I'm working on a demo using a different version of the slice library.  It's based on a `ReplaySubject` so it always provides the last value.

Comment: I produced a demo of the problem.  If we use `of` the route resolves, but if we use `observeLoading$` then the route does not resolve, but it still makes it to the point where it is logging that is creating the Post.

Comment: toPromise returns a promise that resolves when the observable *completes*. Why not just return the observable?

Comment: I wrote an article about it - toPromise() allows us to use `await` and return the value directly https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/implementing-an-angular-post-resolver-backed-by-a-slice-estore-6a2bc0d9871a

Comment: Note that with async/await that actually means returning a promise of the value, **not** returning the value, and that the signature also accepts observables of the value. Also your explanation of why you need takeWhile from your answer below and that Medium post is wrong.

Comment: Without the takeWhile Angular just hangs.  With the takeWhile Angular it works ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Try forking the demo in the medium post and removing the takeWhile and you'll see what I mean ...

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work. I said your explanation is wrong.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What's the right explanation?

Comment: As I told you above, and as the Angular docs I've pointed you to on GitHub say, it's about *completing* the observable, for both toPromise and the resolver machinery. It hangs because you haven't ended the stream. takeWhile, take and of all compete.

Comment: IIUC takeWhile ends the stream ...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to complete the stream or limit the notifications to only one `false` value using `takeWhile` like this:

```
        const topic = await this.cs.loadingTopicStore$.pipe(
            takeWhile(v => v != false, true),
            switchMap((v) => { ...
```